# $x^2+y^2\le 1$; $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$; and $x^2+y^2=4-z$

Tags: integration, contour-integration, riemann-integration, surface-integrals

I need to find a value and "surface" of a body which is contained in the following contours: $x^2+y^2\le 1$; $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$; and $x^2+y^2=4-z$.
Some hints and directions will be helpful.
Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

The surface $x=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ is the "bottom". The surface $x^2+y^2=1$ is the "side". And $z=4-x^2-y^2$ is the "ceiling".

So the volume is 
$$
V=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1[(4-r^2)-r]\,r\,dr.
$$
For the surface, you will have to find the area of each of the bottom, side, and ceiling. For this, you will need to calculate the intersections.